Is there a way to use the SLICE function within the SoQL $query parameter?
I'm working with a database containing a column which contains values all following a fixed format: 2 letters followed by 4 digits, e.g. CW1234. Only the combination of both letters matters to me; here that would be "CW". Digits are of no importance.
What I'm trying to achieve is to create a SoQL $query that outputs the distinct letter combinations found in the column and the count thereof in JSON format. For instance:
CW: 25  // meaning there are 25 codes found starting with "CW"
TO: 103
QZ: 5117
..etc

I tried working with the slice function to select only the first 2 characters (which are the letters) from the column values:
$query=select Code, count(slice(Code,0,2)) group by Code

...but that results in an error query.soql.no-such-function. I guess slice is not supported for $query?
Is there a way to achieve the desired result using the $query parameter alone, or would it require additional processing? For instance a combination of:
$query=select Code

...followed by grabbing the JSON output and locally processing it using PHP.
I'd rather not create a list of all possible letter combinations of A-Z and having to probe all of those individually. An approach using group by methodology would be the most efficient I think (when possible of course).
Any suggestions are much appreciated.
